# biblatex: Sort accented letters into regular letter category

Tags: biblatex, biber

I want to have a large capital letter before every alphabetic section in the bibliography. The following .bib entry causes the error "Package biblatex Error: Category 'Ç' not declared. \endentry":

```
@Article{Cakir2011,
  author    = {Esra {\c{C}}ak{\i}r and E. Allen Foegeding},
  journal   = {Food Hydrocolloids},
  title     = {Combining protein micro-phase separation and protein{\textendash}polysaccharide segregative phase separation to produce gel structures},
  year      = {2011},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {1538-1546},
  volume    = {25},
}
```

In the .bbl file, it turns out this:

```
family={{Ç}ak{ı}r},
           familyi={Ç\bibinitperiod},
```

Hence, biblatex tries to sort this entry into the Category Ç, which doesn't exist. How do I force biblatex to sort entries with an accented first letter of the family name into the Category of the regular letter - in this case, C?

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\cakir.bib}

@Article{Cakir2011,
    author    = {Esra {\c{C}}ak{\i}r and E. Allen Foegeding},
    journal   = {Food Hydrocolloids},
    title     = {Combining protein micro-phase separation and protein{\textendash}polysaccharide segregative phase separation to produce gel structures},
    year      = {2011},
    number    = {6},
    pages     = {1538-1546},
    volume    = {25},
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
citestyle=authoryear,
giveninits=true,
maxbibnames=10,
date=year,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
url=false
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\cakir.bib}

%%-- large initial letter before every new alphabetic section
\makeatletter
\def\ifskipbib{\iftoggle{blx@skipbib}}
\makeatother

\def\initlist{}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\initlist}{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z}
\forlistloop{\DeclareBibliographyCategory}{\initlist}
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\defbibheading{#1}{\section*{#1}}}
\dolistloop{\initlist}
\AtDataInput{\ifskipbib{}{\addtocategory{\thefield{sortinit}}{\thefield{entrykey}}}}

\begin{document}

This scientist's last name begins with an accented letter: \cite{Cakir2011}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is probably simplest to fill the `sortname` field with the name stripped of all diacritics.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
  giveninits=true, maxbibnames=10,
  date=year,
  isbn=false, doi=false, url=false
]{biblatex}


\makeatletter
\def\ifskipbib{\iftoggle{blx@skipbib}}
\makeatother

\def\initlist{}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\initlist}{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z}
\forlistloop{\DeclareBibliographyCategory}{\initlist}
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\defbibheading{#1}{\section*{#1}}}
\dolistloop{\initlist}

\AtDataInput{%
  \ifskipbib
    {}
    {\addtocategory{\thefield{sortinit}}{\thefield{entrykey}}}}



\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Cakir2011,
  author    = {Esra Çakır and E. Allen Foegeding},
  sortname  = {Esra Cakir and E. Allen Foegeding},
  journal   = {Food Hydrocolloids},
  title     = {Combining protein micro-phase separation and
               protein--polysaccharide segregative phase separation
               to produce gel structures},
  year      = {2011},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {1538-1546},
  volume    = {25},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\nocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,cicero,coleridge,cotton}
\begin{document}
This scientist's last name begins with an accented letter: \cite{Cakir2011}.

\printbibheading
\bibbycategory
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with Çakır listed under C.]

---

For the fun of it, here is a solution that works with the Unicode (LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX) engines and lets you remap accented chars.

You would say

```
\remapaccentedchar{Ç}{C}
```

to map Ç into the C category.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=authoryear,
  giveninits=true, maxbibnames=10,
  date=year,
  isbn=false, doi=false, url=false
]{biblatex}


\makeatletter
\def\ifskipbib{\iftoggle{blx@skipbib}}
\makeatother

\def\initlist{}
\forcsvlist{\listadd\initlist}{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z}
\forlistloop{\DeclareBibliographyCategory}{\initlist}
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\defbibheading{#1}{\section*{#1}}}
\dolistloop{\initlist}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\remapaccentedchar}[2]{%
  \csdef{remap@initial@#1}{#2}}

\AtDataInput{%
  \ifskipbib
    {}
    {\ifcsundef{remap@initial@\thefield{sortinit}}
       {\edef\my@init{\thefield{sortinit}}}
       {\letcs\my@init{remap@initial@\thefield{sortinit}}}
      \addtocategory{\my@init}{\thefield{entrykey}}}}
\makeatother

\remapaccentedchar{Ç}{C}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Cakir2011,
  author    = {Esra Çakır and E. Allen Foegeding},
  journal   = {Food Hydrocolloids},
  title     = {Combining protein micro-phase separation and
               protein--polysaccharide segregative phase separation
               to produce gel structures},
  year      = {2011},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {1538-1546},
  volume    = {25},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\nocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,cicero,coleridge,cotton}
\begin{document}
This scientist's last name begins with an accented letter: \cite{Cakir2011}.

\printbibheading
\bibbycategory
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pragmatic solution. First, define the following, initially quaint-looking, macro:

```
\newcommand\noopsort[1]{}
```

Second, change the `author` field from

```
    author    = {Esra {\c{C}}ak{\i}r and E. Allen Foegeding},
```

to

```
    author    = {Esra \noopsort{Cakir}{\c{C}}ak{\i}r and E. Allen Foegeding},
```

Third, run a full recompile cycle: latex-biber-latex.

The point of the `\noopsort` macro is hopefully clear: While LaTeX will typeset the surname as `Çakır` (since it will discard the argument of `\noopsort`), biber will "see" and process the surname as `CakirÇakır` -- and thus correctly sort it under `C`.

By the way, the `\noopsort` trick has a decades-long history with BibTeX. Nice to see that it continues to work with biblatex/biber. :-)